# custom kABPersonInstantMessageProperty

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts, abaddressbook

I am working on an app that requires me to set `kABPersonInstantMessageProperty` or `kABPersonSocialProfileProperty` to my app.This properties when set are displayed in the contacts of the user.But the problem is that they have predefined keys like `kABPersonSocialProfileServiceTwitter`,`kABPersonInstantMessageServiceSkype` etc.

Is there any way I can set this keys to the app I am working on i.e is there any way to add custom keys and set them.I have searched for it but all are for existing social and instant messaging apps.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

We can use any other string in place of the constants.i.e instead of kABPersonInstantMessageServiceSkype  use @"abc".

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/address_book_constants/social_profile_services?language=objc), no custom keys can be added:

> Neither developers nor users can add more keys.

Quoted from the *Overview* section.